# IL Method Call always return null

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

i'm trying do make a custom proxy using Reflection Emit (IL Code).
Everything is working fine, but when i call a second method i always get no result and i get an execption trying to unbox a null value (NullReferenceException).

Here is the IL Code Generated dynamically using Emit. (I've commented the important parts)

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance int32  TestCall(int32 A_1,
                                 int32 A_2) cil managed
{
  // Code size       155 (0x9b)
  .maxstack  5
  .locals init (class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo V_0,
           class [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.TestClass V_1,
           object[] V_2,
           bool V_3,
           object V_4)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4     0x2
  IL_0005:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Object
  IL_000a:  stloc.2
  IL_000b:  ldloc.2
  IL_000c:  ldc.i4     0x0
  IL_0011:  ldarg      A_1
  IL_0015:  nop
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_001c:  stelem.ref
  IL_001d:  ldloc.2
  IL_001e:  ldc.i4     0x1
  IL_0023:  ldarg      A_2
  IL_0027:  nop
  IL_0028:  nop
  IL_0029:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_002e:  stelem.ref
  IL_002f:  ldtoken    [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.TestClass
  IL_0034:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_0039:  ldstr      "TestCall"
  IL_003e:  call       instance class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo [mscorlib]System.Type::GetMethod(string)
  IL_0043:  stloc.0
  IL_0044:  ldarg.0
  IL_0045:  ldfld      class [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.TestClass TestClassProxy::wrappedObject
  IL_004a:  stloc.1
  IL_004b:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_004c:  stloc.3
  IL_004d:  ldarg.0
  IL_004e:  ldfld      class [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.BasicInterceptor TestClassProxy::interception
  IL_0053:  ldloc.0
  IL_0054:  ldloc.2
  IL_0055:  ldloc.1
  IL_0056:  ldloca.s   V_3
  IL_0058:  callvirt   instance object [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.BasicInterceptor::Before(class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo,
                                                                                                     object[],
                                                                                                     object,
                                                                                                     bool&) 
  **//Here everything is ok, i can get the result.**
  IL_005d:  box        [mscorlib]System.Object
  IL_0062:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_0064:  nop
  IL_0065:  ldloc.3
  IL_0066:  brfalse.s  IL_0093
  IL_0068:  ldarg.0
  IL_0069:  ldfld      class [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.TestClass TestClassProxy::wrappedObject
  IL_006e:  ldloc.2
  IL_006f:  ldc.i4     0x0
  IL_0074:  ldelem.ref
  IL_0075:  unbox.any  [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_007a:  ldloc.2
  IL_007b:  ldc.i4     0x1
  IL_0080:  ldelem.ref
  IL_0081:  unbox.any  [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0086:  callvirt   instance int32 [BaseProxy.Console]BaseProxy.Console.TestClass::TestCall(int32,
                                                                                               int32)
  **\\This Call Always return nothing (null)**
  IL_008b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Object
  IL_0090:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_0092:  nop
  IL_0093:  ldloc.s    V_4
  **\\And i get a Exception here because loc 4 is null**
  IL_0095:  unbox.any  [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_009a:  ret
} // end of method TestClassProxy::TestCall
```

The TestCall Method is a very simple method that returns a int32 value.
I've placed a break point inside TestCall and its hiting fine.

PEVerify returned me the follwing error:

```
[IL]: Error: [GeneratedProxyModule.dll : TestClassProxy::TestCall][offset 0x0000008B][found Int32][expected ref 'System.Object'] Unexpected type on the stack.
```

Any help apretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you simplify your code, so that it doesn't contain anything not related to the question? Also, could you provide code that we could actually try? (Including the `Emit()` code, again, after removing irrelevant parts.)

Comment: Also, have you tried running PEVerify on your code?

Comment: Hail svick, thanks for your help, ill try simplify my code.
For now, i've updated the PEVerify result in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PEVerify output tells you exactly what the problem is. The box instruction at 8B expected `Object` on the stack, but at the time, `Int32` was there. But we want to have `Int32` there, that's what we want to box. So why does `box` expect `Object`? Because you told it so. [The parameter to `box` tells it *from* what type to box, not *to* what type to box.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.box.aspx)

So, changing your code to:

```
IL_008b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
```

should fix your problem.

Although all the instructions between 8B and 95 look like a complicated way to do nothing (box, store, load, unbox) to me. If you don't have any special reason to have them there, you should just remove them.

Comment: You're right, now its working fine.. Thnaks alot. =]. About the lines between 8B and 95, its there because of the "if" i'm doing. I'll try to otimize and remove this redundances. Thanks again.